# Need logo on the left and links on the right

Tags: html, css

Currently I'm making navbar for my website, but have this issue: I need logo to be on the left and links on the right. I tried to find some solutions for this, but didn't find any. I'm using `nav` element and float didn't worked.

Here is my code:

```css
* {margin: 0;}

nav {
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    padding: 20px 15px;
    color: #344E41;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: right;
    background: aqua;
}

nav a {
    color: #344E41;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 0px 20px;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

nav a:hover {
    opacity: 75%;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/oqbjv.png" height="50px">
  <a id="nav_a" href="#link1">link1</a>
  <a id="nav_a" href="#link2">link2</a>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply add `margin-right: auto` to the `img`, and it would do the job, like so:

```css
* {margin: 0;}

nav {
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    padding: 20px 15px;
    color: #344E41;
    align-items: center;
    background: aqua;
    gap:20px;
}

nav a {
    color: #344E41;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
nav img{
 margin-right:auto;
}
nav a:hover {
    opacity: 75%;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/oqbjv.png" height="50px">
  <a id="nav_a" href="#link1">link1</a>
  <a id="nav_a" href="#link2">link2</a>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put logo in a `<div>` and the links in another `<div>` and then use `text-align:left;` and `width:1300px;` to image div so the logo will go to the left.

```css
* {margin: 0;}

nav {
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    padding: 20px 15px;
    color: #344E41;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: right;
    background: aqua;
}

nav a {
    color: #344E41;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 0px 20px;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

nav a:hover {
    opacity: 75%;
}

#img {
    text-align: left;
    width: 1300px;
}
.img {
    text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>
<body>
  <nav>
    <div id="img">
    <img class="img" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/oqbjv.png" height="50px">
    </div>
    <div>
      <a id="nav_a" href="#link1">link1</a>
    <a id="nav_a" href="#link2">link2</a>
    </div>
    
</nav>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Code-only answers are considered low quality. Without sufficient explanation, your answer is hard to understand.
If the OP can't understand your answer, then he also won't be able to reproduce your possible solution. As such it 
would be worthless to him/her. Please add a sufficient explanation of your possible solution.

Comment: @tacoshy Well it is their own code and they obviously know what is changed in their code and what is added but you are right, its better to add explanation and I will add so if you can fix that downvote ty.

Answer (score -1):

Since you are using flexbox, you can set the direction of the elements. Adding to your nav CSS the property:

`flex-direction: row;`

This should display the elements horizontally to the right.

Comment: When i done that, nothing changed.

Comment: it will not align the links to the right by default you miss at least one steps to a full solution. Besides that, `flex-direction: row` is the default value for `Flexbox`.